# React Native map tracing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I wrote a map to trace values coming from the storefront , but somehow it's unable to break the loop when certain condition met in the loop
can you please let me know how to traverse a map in react native and how to break once a certain condition met

`````
    this.setState({
      showDropDown:false,
      selectedOption:[{key:newId,value:selectedValue}]
    })
   }else{
  selectedOption.filter(select=>{
    if(select.key === newId){
     return ( this.setState({
      selectedOption:[...this.state.selectedOption,{key:newId,value:selectedValue}]
    }))
    }
    else{
     return  (this.setState({
      selectedOption:[...this.state.selectedOption,{key:newId,value:selectedValue}]
    }))
    }
  })
  }````
`````

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are returning from inside the function you passed to the filter function, which will iterate over all elements and return those who returned true.

You should use the some function, which stops when the first true value is returned. So replace `selectedOption.filter` with `selectedOption.some`.